# R copy files with file names that are %in% a list

Tags: r

I would like to copy only a subset of thousands of files to another folder. I use the %in% command to find the names of the files I would like to copy, which works. The only part that doesn't work is the actual file.copy() command, which results in all FALSE printed to the console. What's the error?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(here)

control_IDs <- c(1,2,3,4) 

files <- list.files(here("data", "user_files_2021"), full.names = TRUE)
                    
control_files <- files[sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(files)) %in% control_IDs]

file.copy(file.path(control_files), here("data"))
```

Comment: can you show the output when you print `files` and `control_files` to console?

Comment: Sure, it's like this (simplified example of real thing)
files: 
[1] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.1.csv"
[2] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.2.csv"
[3] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.3.csv"
[4] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.4.csv"
[5] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.5.csv"
[6] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.6.csv"
control_files:
[1] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.1.csv"
[2] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.2.csv"
[3] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.3.csv"
[4] "C:/Users/username/data/user_files_2021.4.csv"

Comment: It looks like you are copying the files to the same location where they already exist.

Comment: Ah, there were earlier versions of the file in the new folder. I had to add overwrite = TRUE to make it work. Thanks - your comment helped because it made me realize this, d'oh. Thanks!